# asp.net Compilation Error (mysql.data)

Tags: asp.net, mysql

i have an error when trying to start default.aspx.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' exists in both 
'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\6.3.6.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\elwazefa\fd12d8de\3446c68c\assembly`\dl3\dc121b8b\00d6e0c3_62aacb01\MySql.Data.CF.DLL'`
```

*i am using asp.net 3.5*
what is the problem, thanks

Comment: Try deleting the temporary file they mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you have references to both the Compact Framework and the standard framework MySQL libraries in your project. You need to remove the references to the ones that have .CF in their filename.

Comment: I don't have CF. what should i do then?

Comment: You have the exact same error message, but don't have CF? You do have CF if you're getting that error message. If you are getting a different error, open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file `assemblies` section for multiple references:

```
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    ...             
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

If there is more than one then remove it (the one not in the GAC, I would say off-hand.)

Also, as @Abe suggests, delete the temporary files under the following path:

> `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`

Comment: i didnt fine ant duplicates in the assemblies and i tried to remove the temp files which made work on local host but it still doesnt work on the actual host